# View hits by domain name in Google Analytics

Tags: google, google-analytics

I have multiple domains and I set the appropriate settings in the javascript code but in Google Analytics I would like to see the number of page views by each domain. I can't seem to find this report.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am sort of a newbie at GA.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you set up cross domain tracking - how did you configure the urls to point to your site and could you provide more on how you set up analytics?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you are viewing hits by a dimension, go to Secondary Dimension and select Behavior > Hostname.

[image: Hostname filter]

This should further divide the dimension by domain names. If you want to include or exclude specific domains, once you have added the hostname dimension you can click on "advanced" and add rules that define the behavior you are looking for.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To just see hostname by pageviews, you can create a custom report listing all the domains. To do this go to Customization on the top left of the left menu, then hit custom reports, then click the New custom report button.

In the new custom report, use the primary dimension of hostname and add metrics like impressions for hits and any others you'd like to include. Then save and allow the report to run, below is hostname and a couple of metrics I'd recommend.

[image]